# Why isn't my DateTime field populating?

Tags: apex, rest, datetime

I am trying to push leads into Salesforce and I am passing in the following value...

Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c=2021-12-14T18:27:33Z

This format appears to match the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ format listed in the documentation. When I check the lead, it successfully pushed into Salesforce but the field Requested_Appointment_DateTime is still null. Any ideas?

Edit:  I tried some execute anonymous tests to see if I could assign the date as shown... but it's saying invalid date/time. This matches the docs though?!

```
Lead l = [Select id, Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c from Lead where id='00Q3o00001AuWTOEA3'];
l.Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c = DateTime.parse('2021-12-14T18:27:33Z');
system.debug(l.Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c);
```

When I try to set the time to system.now() it returns something that looks like '2021-12-14 18:27:33' with no T or Z... when I try and parse that string it says invalid date. What is the correct date format??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were expecting the lead record to display the new value, you forgot the step where you save the data back to the database.

```
Lead l = [Select id, Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c from Lead where id='00Q3o00001AuWTOEA3'];
l.Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c = DateTime.valueOfGmt('2021-12-14 18:27:33');
system.debug(l.Requested_Appointment_DateTime__c);
update l;
```

Comment: No, I was expecting the value to assign correctly. It throws an error saying it could not parse this date format. This apex code is just for demonstration that the field isn't setting via api call. I'm sure the format is right... that's what's on the docs and in all the questions I looked at. Am I missing something obvious here? The error is
System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2021-12-14 18:27:33

Comment: @PaulyP For API calls, you use the specific format you found in the docs. This is the ISO8601 date time format supported by Salesforce. Using DateTime.valueOf or DateTime.parse requires a different format. I've edited this answer to reflect the correct format. If the value is null, there may be another reason, either an automation or code that is clearing out the field mid-transaction.

Comment: Have you tried Datetime.valueOf ? Yes, what Sfdcfox said

Comment: @sfdcfox When I submit using the ISO8601 format it does not populate. This is a new field so no existing automations would update it.  Would it matter that this is a web-to-lead submission?

Comment: @PaulyP Yes, web-to-lead expects it to be in a locale-dependent format. Try "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa", such as *12/14/2021 6:27 pm*

Comment: @sfdcfox Once again my hero! Thank you. Does this account for timezone? The passed time is in UTC... should the timezone be factored in before the date is pushed into web-to-lead?

Comment: @PaulyP From what I can tell, time zones are captured in the Default Timezone for your organization. Some translation may be required if you expect leads to come from many different timezones. In addition, the format required will depend on your organization's Default Locale. For this, and a variety of other reasons, it's usually recommended that you avoid W2L if you have more advanced developer resources available (e.g. use an API).